# recode can not find files when is running as a nautilus script

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I created a `Nautilus Action` script to change file encoding using `recode` application.
My action is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
ToolbarLabel[en_US]=Convert Encoding From Windows-12
ToolbarLabel[en]=Convert Encoding From Windows-12
ToolbarLabel[C]=Convert Encoding From Windows-12
Tooltip[en_US]=Converts file content encoding from Windows-1256 and saves as UTF-8
Tooltip[en]=Converts file content encoding from Windows-1256 and saves as UTF-8
Tooltip[C]=Converts file content encoding from Windows-1256 and saves as UTF-8
Name[en_US]=Convert Encoding From Windows-1256
Name[en]=Convert Encoding From Windows-1256
Name[C]=Convert Encoding From Windows-1256
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
SelectionCount==1
MimeTypes=all/allfiles;
Matchcase=false
Basenames=*.srt;
Exec=recode windows-1256 "%F"
Name[en_US]=Default profile
Name[en]=Default profile
Name[C]=Default profile
ExecutionMode=DisplayOutput
```

The code worked properly for a while but now it fails!
When I set action's `ExecutionMode` to `DisplayOutput` it displays this:

```
Run command:
/bin/sh -c 'recode  windows-1256 "'\''/home/ariyan/a.srt'\''"'

Standard output:


Standard error:
recode: fopen ('/home/ariyan/a.srt'): No such file or directory
```

it can't find the file while it is there! (When I run the same command in a terminal window it works)
What is the problem ?
Why `sh` can't find the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quotes in command!
using `recode windows-1256 %F` instead of `recode windows-1256 "%F"` solved the problem!